# What does "Invalid operands to binary expression (ostream and void)" mean, and how can it be fixed?

Tags: c++, cout, ostream

I'm encountering an error that says:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'void')

I understand there are some questions related to this error posted on StackOverflow but I need some help and explanations regarding this specific context on what this error means.

In the `main()` function, I create a student object called `s1`. The error happens in `main()` where I'm trying to get the results of his GPA using a method of the `Student` class called `getResults(double gpa)`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Human{
    protected: string name;
    protected: int age;
    
public: Human(){
        name = "Unknown";
        age = 5;
    }
    
public:
    Human(string name, int age){
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
}
    
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    
    void setName(string name){
        this->name = name;
    }
    
    void setAge(int age){
        this->age = age;
    }        
};

class Student: public Human{
    protected: string school;
    protected: double gpa;
    
public:
    Student(string name, int age, string school, double gpa) : Human(name, age){
        this->school = school;
        this->gpa = gpa;
    }
    
    double getGPA(){
        return gpa;
    }
    
    string getSchool(){
        return school;
    }
    
    void setGPA(double gpa){
        this->gpa = gpa;
    }
    
    void setSchool(string school){
        this->school = school;
    }
    
    void getResult(double gpa){
        if (gpa < 3.0) {
            cout << "You did well!";
        } else {
            cout << "Try harder next time";
        }
    }
    
};

int main() {
    Student s1 ("John", 23, 'm', "University of Chicago", 3.4);
    double s1GPA = s1.getGPA();
    cout << s1.getResult(s1GPA) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getResult()` doesn't return anything and it is declared as `void`. Trying to output the `void` upsets the compiler because streams don't know how to output `void`.

Comment: C++ isn't Java. You don't have to decorate every member with an access specifier. Just one `protected:` and one `public:` will be sufficient, for example, in class `Human`.

Comment: You really need to start by reading the book, not my asking SO folks. You are trying to code Java in C++, and this won't take you anywhere.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `this->` syntax to access members, if the members and method parameters *have different names*.

Comment: Another thing is, your code has **accessors** -  dreaded **setter** and **getter**. They are Gog and Magog of programming, run away from them!

Comment: @SergeyA so what do you suggest instead of getters and setters? :)

Comment: @SebastienSim Expose the member as public, of course!

Comment: @SergeyA ahhh okay! Got it. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @SergeyA setter and getters aren't bad unless you're using them unnecessarily. While in OP's case I don't think he really needs them, having getters and setters are actually *good* design if you have data that needs to be kept secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your `getResults` function has a `void` return type, which means it doesn't actually return *anything*. Because of this, do not try to `cout` the result of this function in your main.

Consider the following edit:

```
// Your result is printed within this function
s1.getResult(s1GPA);

// Print a new line if you wish
cout << endl;
```

Also, since your `getResults` doesn't really *get* anything, I'd suggest changing the name to something like `printResults`.

**Note**

Notice how in your `getResult` it doesn't *return* anything because it's a void. In this function, you're just outputting text to the console with `cout`:

```
// Notice that this function doesn't actually return anything
void getResult(double gpa){
    if (gpa < 3.0) {
        // Output this message to console
        cout << "You did well!";
    } else {
        // Output this message to console
        cout << "Try harder next time";
    }
}
```

When you have the statement in your main, it's trying to `cout` **nothing** because `getResult` is a void:

```
cout << s1.getResult(s1GPA) << endl;
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//      This doesn't return anything for cout to output.
```

That is why you only need to call `getResult` instead of trying to `cout` it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! But i'm just curious, so I can't cout in the methods? I have to always return a string or something?

Comment: You can `cout` in functions; my answer is just saying when you call that function, don't try to `cout` it because it `getResult` itself doesn't return anything that you can `cout`. I'll try to make an edit to my answer to help clear this up :)

Comment: oh okay! i'll camp around here then. Thanks!

Comment: ohh! it makes so much sense. thank you! I understand now @Nick Z. Thanks!