# invalid operands to binary expression?

Tags: c++, inheritance, binary, expression, operands

I am trying to implement classes that use inheritance/polymorphism and I cant figure out why I am getting this error:

> invalid operands to binary expression error ('basic_ostream<char,std::_1::char_traits>' and 'void')

The error is within the function called animate below, where it is surrounded by two **, right above the main.   The `c->move` is giving this error for some reason, but `c->name` doesn't. I've implemented everything else, and everything else seems to work properly. It's just this one error. Can someone please explain what is going on?  Basically, the base class here is creature, and all the other classes are deriving from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Creature {
public:
    Creature(string new_name) {
        its_name=new_name;
    }
    virtual void move() const=0;
    virtual bool isMortal() const =0;
    string name() const {
        return its_name;
    }

    virtual ~Creature();
    
private:
    string its_name;
    
};

class Phoenix:public Creature {
public:
    Phoenix(string new_name):Creature(new_name) {};
    virtual void move() const{
        cout<<"Squawkes, who is immortal, will now fly.";
    }
    virtual bool isMortal() const {
        return false;
    }
    
    virtual ~Phoenix();
};

class Giant:public Creature {
public:  
    Giant(string new_name,int new_lbs): Creature(new_name) {
        lbs=new_lbs;
        
    }
    virtual void move() const {
        if (lbs<20) {
            cout<<"Frawp, who is mortal, will now tromp.";
        }
        else {
            cout<<"Gridwulfa, who is mortal, will now lumber.";
        }
    }
    virtual bool isMortal() const {
        return true;
    }
    
    virtual ~Giant();
private:
    int lbs;
};

class Centaur:public Creature {
public:
    Centaur(string new_name):Creature(new_name) {};
    virtual void move() const{
        cout<<"Squawkes, who is immortal, will now fly.";
    }
    virtual bool isMortal() const {
        return false;
    }
    
    virtual~Centaur();
};

void animate(const Creature* c)  //need to add & or is * sufficient?
{
    cout << c->name() << ", who is ";
    if (c->isMortal())
        cout << "mortal";
    else
        cout << "immortal";
    **cout << ", will now " << c->move() << ".\n";**
}

Here is my main:

int main() {
    
    Creature* creatures[4];
    creatures[0] = new Phoenix("Squawkes");
    // Giants have a name and a weight in tons.  Giants under 20 tons
    // walk by tromping; giants weighing at least 20 tons lumber.
    creatures[1] = new Giant("Frawp", 17);
    creatures[2] = new Giant("Gridwulfa", 22);
    creatures[3] = new Centaur("Florence");
    
    cout << "Here are the creatures." << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        animate(creatures[k]);
    
    // Clean up the creatures before exiting
    cout << "Cleaning up." << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        delete creatures[k];


}
```

I'm not supposed to change main or animate. I have to implement all the classes properly

Comment: The error message says what is wrong. You cannot `<<` a  stream with a void.

Comment: `move` should return a string; a single verb ("lumber", "fly", "tromp"). You have hardcoded the string that `animate` is supposed to build in `move`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my method to recognize my object value in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34163958/90527)

Answer (score 0):

Return type of your function is `void` :

```
void Creature::move()
```

you cannot send a void to a stream, you need to return something printable, string, int, bool, whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Creature {
public:
    Creature(string new_name) {
        its_name=new_name;
    }
    virtual std::string move() const=0;
    virtual bool isMortal() const =0;
    string name() const {
        return its_name;
    }

    virtual ~Creature();

private:
    string its_name;

};

class Phoenix:public Creature {
public:
    Phoenix(string new_name):Creature(new_name) {};
    virtual std::string move() const{
        return "fly";
    }
    virtual bool isMortal() const {
        return false;
    }

    virtual ~Phoenix();
};

class Giant:public Creature {
public:  
    Giant(string new_name,int new_lbs): Creature(new_name) {
        lbs=new_lbs;

    }
    virtual std::string move() const {
        if (lbs<20)
            return  "tromp";
        return "lumber";
    }
    virtual bool isMortal() const {
        return true;
    }

    virtual ~Giant();
private:
    int lbs;
};

class Centaur:public Creature {
public:
    Centaur(string new_name):Creature(new_name) {};
    virtual std::string move() const{
        return "fly";
    }
    virtual bool isMortal() const {
        return false;
    }

    virtual~Centaur();
};

void animate(const Creature* c)  //need to add & or is * sufficient?
{
    cout << c->name() << ", who is ";
    if (c->isMortal())
        cout << "mortal";
    else
        cout << "immortal";
    **cout << ", will now " << c->move() << ".\n";**
}


int main() {

    Creature* creatures[4];
    creatures[0] = new Phoenix("Squawkes");
    // Giants have a name and a weight in tons.  Giants under 20 tons
    // walk by tromping; giants weighing at least 20 tons lumber.
    creatures[1] = new Giant("Frawp", 17);
    creatures[2] = new Giant("Gridwulfa", 22);
    creatures[3] = new Centaur("Florence");

    cout << "Here are the creatures." << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        animate(creatures[k]);

    // Clean up the creatures before exiting
    cout << "Cleaning up." << endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        delete creatures[k];


}
```