# Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>' and 'void')

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to write a function to solve a quadratic equation, and I get this error on line 26:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>' and 'void')
```

But I don't quite understand why the compiler swears and what it wants from me. I connected the  library `<ostream>`, but it didn't work. Please help me figure it out! Thanks.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

void Kva(float a,float b, float c)
{
    float Diskr, x1, x2;

    Diskr = (b*b) - (4*a*c);

    if (Diskr >= 0)
    {x1 = ((-b) - sqrt(Diskr))/(2*a);
    x2 = ((-b) + sqrt(Diskr))/(2*a);
    cout << "x1 =" << " " << x1 << ";" << " " << "x2 =" << " " << x2 << endl;}
    else {cout << "Diskriminant < 0" << endl;}

    //return x1;
}

int main()
{
    float a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << Kva(a, b, c) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to print the result of the call `Kva(a, b, c)`, but that call doesn't in fact return any result; the function is declared to return `void`. That is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: `Kva()` returns `void` but there is no overload for `operator<<(std::ostream&, void)` nor can it be defined. (`void` is not a valid type for a function/operator parameter.) You cannot use `Kva()` in `cout << Kva(a, b, c) << endl;`. This is what the error is about.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 
Thank you! I think about it.
I want to output x1 and x2 when user enters his values a, b and c. But if I'm not writing a void function, but, for example, float, then I don't know how to return both "x", and not just one of them

Comment: Currently, you made the output inside of `Kva()`. Thus, just calling `Kva(a, b, c);` would do the output. However, there are various ways to return multiple values from a function. One of them is, to group the individual values in one, e.g. with a `struct` or `std::tuple`. (If you want to use the return value directly with `std::cout`, you had to provide another overload for `operator<<`. But you just can assign the return value to a local variable and then do the output as usual.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Invalid operands to binary expression (ostream and void)" mean, and how can it be fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34163958/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the prototype of your function:

```
void Kva(float a, float b, float c)
```

You are telling the compiler to pass nothing. You may want to ask the function to return the `float` type. Uncomment the return statement.

For `x1` in `Kva()`, remember to initialize it so that it guarantees to return some value to the function (at least zero) to avoid any unwanted results.

Comment: Thank you! 
I tried to introduce a function that returns float, but I don't understand how I can get x1 and x2 in this case, and not just x1

Comment: @Max You can only return one primitive-type value at a time. However, you can make some conditions to tell the function when to return `x1` and when `x2`.

Comment: @Max You could, for example, return a std::pair<float,float> or you could return by reference in the argument list.