# Why does outputting the return value of a void function fail?

Tags: c++, string, ascii

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void subseq(string s, string ans)
{
    if (s.size() == 0)
    {
        cout <<ans<< endl;
    }
    char ch = s[0];
    int code = ch;
    string ros = s.substr(1);
    subseq(ros, ans);
    subseq(ros, ans+ch);
    subseq(ros, ans + std::to_string(code));
   
}

int main()
{
    cout<<subseq("AB", " ");

    return 0;
}
```

Error, as stated in IDE, are : All paths through this function will call itself
Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'void')

Comment: I took the liberty of making the title more readable/findable. Admittedly there is a touch of solution in the title now. Feel free to undo my change, but please try for a briefer title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Invalid operands to binary expression (ostream and void)" mean, and how can it be fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34163958/90527)

Answer (score 2):

Both problems

- endless recursion, "All paths through this function will call itself" is the tipoff here
- attempt to output a `void` value

can be handled by using some well-placed `return`s and a meaningful return type for `subseq`.

For that, reason to yourself how you get out of this broken recursion. At which point of the function do you NOT want the rest to be executed.
Also at which point do you know the result which you want to output. What data type does it have, you need to declare that type as return value.