# "invalid operands to binary expression" in simple class using memory and addresses

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
public:

    string eat()
    {
        return "I can Eat";
    }
    
    string sleep()
    {
        return "I can sleep";
    }
    
    void showData(int *weight, int *age)
    {
        cout << "The weight is " << weight << " and the age is " << age << endl;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    Animal an;
    int x;
    int y;
    cout << "Enter the height and weight of the dog." <<endl;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    
    cout << an.eat()<< endl;
    cout << an.sleep()<<endl;
    cout << an.showData(&x,&y) << endl;
   
    return 0;
}
```

At the part that states:

`cout << an.showData(&x,&y)`

I get an error stating:

> invalid operands to binary expression

I thought that by using addresses, I can instantly be able to output the function, but apparently I guess there is some incompatibility?

Comment: `showData` is declared to not return any value, so what are you trying to do with `cout << an.showData(&x,&y)`?

Comment: Why are you using pointers for `showData`.  You don't need to use pointers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i wanted to use a function with multiple parameters and i though using pointers would help.

Comment: If you are passing a lot of parameters to a function, consider placing them in a `struct` and passing the struct.

Comment: @Shifty Passing *pointers* to integers is not more efficient than passing the *values* of the integers instead. You should prefer passing parameters by value unless you know for sure that passing by reference/pointer is actually better (ie, avoiding copies of non-trivial types).

Comment: *"I thought that by using addresses,"* -- what does this have to do with your error? I would have guessed that when the full error message mentions the types of the operands, it would not mention pointers. Admittedly, that is just a guess. Perhaps you should copy the full error message into your question? The full message should identify where in your code the error occurs (hence which binary operator has invalid operands), as well as the types of the operands. If at least one of those types is a pointer, then "by using addresses" might be relevant.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm assuming that removing the entire body of the `main` function in your edit was accidental, and I have restored it. If you *did* have a reason for doing that, please let me know.

Comment: There was no reason. I think I know what happened, but I'm not quite sure HOW it happened.

Comment: @JaMiT: Note Shifty's comment about using pointers was in response to Thomas Matthews' question about the `showData` arguments and not about the error. The binary operator referred to in the error is `<<`, and the location of the error is as identified in the original post, where the (void) result of `showData` is passed as an argument. You make a good point about including the full error message so as to include type information.

Comment: @outis Note that my comment quoted the question, not a comment. That line from the question predates all existing comments on the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Invalid operands to binary expression (ostream and void)" mean, and how can it be fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163958/what-does-invalid-operands-to-binary-expression-ostream-and-void-mean-and-h)

Comment: @JaMiT: I see what you were referring to now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showData()` returns `void`, ie nothing.  So there is nothing to pass to `operator<<`, hence the error.

Simply change `cout << an.showData(...)` to `an.showData(...)`, since `showData()` does its own `cout` statements internally.

If you want `cout << an.showData(...)` to actually display something, then `showData()` needs to `return` something worth displaying, such as a `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
string showData(int *weight, int *age)
{
    return "The weight is " + to_string(*weight) + " and the age is " + to_string(*age);
}
```

```cpp
Animal an;
cout << an.showData(&x,&y) << endl;
```